# Delphi ListView hint flickers

Tags: delphi

Hints flickers all the time when mouse is moved, even in the same row. Tried set doublebuffered, but no result. Tried also move code to on mouse event but still the same http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2007/qt/listview_hints.htm

```
procedure TForm1.ListView2InfoTip(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem;
  var InfoTip: string);
begin
      InfoTip := 'Gracz: ' + InfoTip + #13#10 + hintyStreamyObecne[Item.Index] ;
end;
```

Im using Delphi XE5. Listview is put on PageControl. I can reproduce the same hint flickers on checkbox when i set very low value for Application.HintPause and check/uncheck checkbox. Using default value for Application.HintPause doesnt help for listView. Event ListView2InfoTip is triggered on every mouse position change. Any suggestion?

Comment: How severe is the flicker. I can see a little in my own app, but only now that you've mentioned it.

Comment: annoying. I uploaded video (mouse not visible, without recording is much more intese) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQf38BM8Kic&feature=youtu.be

Comment: That is indeed very annoying. I have a feeling that the size of the tip makes it worse than mine. Mine is just a single line.

Comment: yes, unfortunetly. Always i can move this extra info into window messages under popup menu, but i hope there will be solution for my problem, cause hints are just better for that.

Comment: I cannot see an easy way out for you. The hint mechanism is buried pretty deep in the VCL.

Comment: I can. A `THintWindow`.

Comment: @TLama Hard to make them have all the behaviour of a hint.

Comment: @David, what's so specific on built-in hints you couldn't do with `THintWindow` ? With `THintWindow` you can make much nicer hints...

Comment: @TLama Hints show for a period, and then disappear. Handled by a timer. Mouse events reset the timer. Using a `THintWindow` would result in a hint that looked different from standard hints. That would grate. Take a look at all the scaffolding in the VCL to show hints. It's buried very deep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the code from Delphi.About.com I recomend you do the next change:

In that code the line

```
li := ListView1.GetItemAt(pt.x, pt.y) ;
```

is used to determine over which item is your mouse cursor positioned.

Now what I would do is create some global variable or even better add another field to ListView component in which I would store reference to last ListItem for which the hint has been shown.

Then I would add simple check to see if the current ListItem gotten by above code is same as the one we stored in the new variable/field. If it is not we triger showing of hint if it is we simply exit the procedure.

```
var oli: TListItem; //Here we store reference to TListItem to which we shown hint last time

implementation

procedure TMyForm.ListView1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);

...
begin
  ...
  li := ListView1.GetItemAt(pt.x, pt.y) ;    
  if oli = li then Exit
  else
    oli := li;
    //hint showing code
  end;
end;
```

This change of code will make sure that new hint will only be shown when the mouse moves over another item and not on every mouse move.

Comment: -1 Hints are handled by the framework at a different level, and the code is very involved. You cannot implement hints by adding a bit of code to a single control's `OnMouseMove` event.

Comment: Zarko Gajic's code from delphi.about.com that OP has referenced actually does that. It dynamically change the hint contents and then force show the hint using Application.ActivateHint(Mouse.CursorPos); The problem OP is expiriencing is that this is fired on every mouse move which results in flickering due to slow hint re/drawing. So I sugested a way to reduce the number of times the hint re/drawing is requested which should get rid of the flickering.

Comment: If you included a complete explanation in the answer then I'd be happy

Comment: Well I just wrote what changes need to be made to Zarko's code. I can write full code when I get home since I currentlya at work without acces to Delphi.

Comment: i think i tried it earlier to reduce hint assign, but i didnt know that i must remove "OnInfoTip" from object inspector - i just remove code between begin end.